# Python - The product of the neighboring numbers in the previous list until only one number remains

Tags: python, list, tuples

From a user-supplied list of values, calculate the number obtained by building a sequence of lists whose items are the product of neighboring numbers in the previous list. For example, if the user-supplied list is [1, 2, 3, 4], the desired number would be 864 because: [1 * 2, 2 * 3, 3 * 4] = [2, 6, 12] ...

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
new_l=[1, 2, 3, 4]
def calculate_product(new_l):
    if len(new_l)>1:
        new_l2=[new_l[x]*new_l[x+1] for x in range(len(new_l)-1)]
        calculate_product(new_l2)
    else:
        print(new_l[0])
calculate_product(new_l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This code works based on the input of the user. Hope you understand this -

```
num = int(input('How many elements in elements?: ')) # This line asks for
the length of elements so that the code works dynamically

n = 0 # Initialising
lst = [] # ``
while n != num:
    a = int(input(f'Enter Element {n+1}: ')) # Asks for input for each element
    lst.append(a)
    n += 1

print('The list generated is',lst)

def getoutput(lst):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        lst = [lst[i]*lst[i+1] for i in range(len(lst)-1)] # Calculating
        getoutput(lst)

    else:
        print(lst[0])
        
print('Output:',end=' ') # Final result (Maybe you do not need `end =' '`)
getoutput(lst)
```